# How can I determine the relative position of option menu objects in the Android ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In the Honeycomb ActionBar, I am trying to determine the position of the icons that appear as my ActionBar's 'showAsAction' options.  Several of my icons are set to appear only if there is room.  I want to include helpful comments under each icon when the application is first run.  To properly position the comments , I need an idea of where these icons are.

I have called getActionBar() from the activity and the icons don't appear in the ActonBar's View.  I know I can get a handle on the Menu Item through the onPrepare and the onCreate for the OptionsMenu, but they don't contain any positioning information since the ActionBar has not been rendered.  Any ideas?  I have also explored the onMenuVisibilityListener, but the ActionBar at that point still does not contain any information that I can use to calculate the relative positions of the option menu icons.

If there is a way to also just determine which actionbar items are actually appearing, I can calculate where to place things too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to include helpful comments under each icon when the application is first run.

Then load a different menu XML resource on the first run, one that has `withText` along with `ifRoom` for `android:showAsAction`.

You could make this a configuration option for the user, so the user gets to choose which style to use.

> If there is a way to also just determine which actionbar items are actually appearing, I can calculate where to place things too.

Except that you can't actually place anything there. The toolbar buttons take up the full action bar height.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear.  I meant I am trying to make a splash screen that points out the different things on the ActionBar with a brief explanation of what an action will do - text that would be more than the one or two words that would go next to the icon if I used 'withText'.  In terms of placing things, I meant that, the text would be a part of the layout that appears below the ActionBar.

Comment: @Steven: That makes a bit more sense, though I don't think that's possible. Certainly, whatever hack you would come up with (e.g., sniffing inside the `View` hierarchy of the `ActionBar`) will not be reliable, as the internal implementation of the `ActionBar` is not documented. While your intention is noble, it's just not a use case that Android supports today.

Comment: Is there a possibility of getting the overall activities view so that I can search for visible Views by their ids?  What I mean is, is there a postCreate sort of event and also a way to get an activities entire view heirarchy?

Comment: @Steven: You can call `findViewById()` any time after `setContentView()` to find widgets that **you inflate yourself**. The action bar is not your code and is not part of the content view. While you are welcome to attempt to navigate up the view hierarchy from the content view, you have no guarantees about what widgets will be there, whether they will be the same on all Android OS versions, etc. You will be breaking encapsulation. Whatever you do will be unreliable, as it will assume the nature of the internal implementation. If you value your users, do not ship unreliable code.

Comment: Thank for the feedback! I'll shelve this for now.